# Post to wall: link in description is removed

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-wall

Our app can post to a friend's wall successfully.  However, if the message contains a url it is auto removed by Facebook.  If manually posting to a friend's wall the link in the message shows up ok.  Is this a Facebook app limitation?  If so, is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: Try using any of these sites that makes your url shorten, I have my app running and posting links on facebook this way with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're doing that to prevent link spam.  Otherwise Facebook would be FILLED with links to pr0n, V14gr4 and w4r3z.

I expect that Facebook is executing a bit of Javascript in your browser when a live human posts to a wall.  That Javascript would let their server know that the link was posed by a browser that supported Javascript.  That's not likely to be the case for web applications that talk HTTP directly.

If I'm correct, then you will either need a Javascript interpreter integrated into your app, or if what Facebook expects as a response is simple enough, then you could just fake it out by sending a canned response.

Try looking at your friend's wall while running a Javascript debugger, then make two posts, one with and one without a link.  You could also place a protocol analyzer between your compuer and the Internet.